# Dynamic Classes in Vue 3 SFC

Tags: vue.js, sass, vuejs3, webpack-5

I try to inject classnames into a Vue 3 component via props and would like to keep the classes defined in the component. Problem is, those classes are not included in the build, since they are "unreferenced".

Is there a way around this?

```html
<script setup lang="ts">    
    const {className} = defineProps<{className: string;}>();    
</script>
<template>
    <div :class="className">Hello</div>
</template>
<style lang="scss" scoped>
    .some-class {
        color: pink;
    }
</style>
```

`.some-class` is not included in the build since it's not directly referenced :-(

The application is built using webpack 5 with vue-style-loader:

```
module: {
    rules: [
        { test: /\.css$/, use: ["vue-style-loader", "css-loader"] },
        {
            test: /\.scss$/,
            use: [
                "vue-style-loader",
                "css-loader",
                {
                    loader: "sass-loader",
                    options: {
                        additionalData: `@import "scss/_variables.scss";`
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

EDIT: Added my rather unspectacular webpack5 config

Thanks

Comment: The compiler is stripping the un-used classes by default? Damn didn't knew that. Quite special for sure.

Comment: Instead of passing classNames as a string, it is always widely accepted and a good practice to instead send optional props that control the style of the underlying component. And then to apply classes based on the options provided to the component. Perhaps what you are experiencing is intended behaviour.

Comment: Yeah @Frostmourne I'm pretty sure it is. Seems useful as well, but in my case it would be quite an effort to move everything into props. I'm refacturing old code and would like to keep it simple :-)

Comment: How did you confirm that it's not included into a build? This is something that is specific to your setup. Did you try something like `<div :class="{ 'some-class': className === 'some-class' } ">` to make sure it works differently?

Comment: Yes @EstusFlask I tried that. No success though :-(

Comment: The problem is potentially specific to your setup, which is unknown. Consider providing a way to reproduce it.

Comment: I agree with @EstusFlask, you should at least provide your builder config file, either it's Vite or Webpack.